# How to insert data in frame using selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am using selenium with python I want to insert the username and email inputs containing in frame
[Here is the link](https://www.collabera.com/find-a-job/search-jobs/job-details/248429-python-developer-jobs-jersey-city-nj/)

I am trying to do this but it's not switching into the modal.

```
 try:
    time.sleep(3)
    driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_id("thanksModal"))
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='file']").send_keys("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\Resume.docx")
    driver.find_element_by_id('txtName').send_keys(name)
    driver.find_element_by_id('txtEmail').send_keys(email)
    driver.find_element_by_id('btnSubmit').click()
    time.sleep(5)
except:
    pass
```

Comment: there is no frame as you provided please add sceens shot of which field in the link  profvided

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The elements are within an `<iframe>` so you have to:

- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the desired *frame to be available and switch to it*.
- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52603847/how-to-sleep-webdriver-in-python-for-milliseconds/52607451#52607451) for the desired *element to be clickable*.
- You can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

  - Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

    ```
    driver.get("https://www.collabera.com/find-a-job/search-jobs/job-details/248429-python-developer-jobs-jersey-city-nj/")
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe.apply-form")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input#txtName"))).send_keys("bhupathi_turaga@stackoverflow.com")
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input#txtEmail").send_keys("bhupathi_turaga@stackoverflow.com")
    ```
  - Using `XPATH`:

    ```
    driver.get("https://www.collabera.com/find-a-job/search-jobs/job-details/248429-python-developer-jobs-jersey-city-nj/")
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[@class='apply-form']")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='txtName']"))).send_keys("bhupathi_turaga@stackoverflow.com")
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='txtEmail']").send_keys("bhupathi_turaga@stackoverflow.com")
    ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
   from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
   from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
   from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: Collabera_iframe]

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [Ways to deal with #document under iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53203417/ways-to-deal-with-document-under-iframe)
- [Switch to an iframe through Selenium and python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834358/switch-to-an-iframe-through-selenium-and-python/44847390#44847390)
- [selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element while trying to click Next button with selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50315587/selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-una/50315715#50315715)
- [selenium in python : NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53441658/selenium-in-python-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-unable-to/53442511#53442511)

Comment: My apology for the delay in response